Springboot war is not deployed under tomcat
I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot app to Tomcat. I created a WAR file, but it does not run on Tomcat, even though it is visible.
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.application.chatsystem'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

war {
    archivesBaseName = 'socialmedia'
}

task build(overwrite: true) {
    dependsOn = ['clean','test','war']
    test.mustRunAfter clean
    war.mustRunAfter test
}

Application file -
package com.application.chatsystem.socialmedia;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

Controller file -
package com.application.chatsystem.socialmedia.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class StatusController {
    @GetMapping("/rest/status")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getStatus() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Working");
    }
}

server.xml file -
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="2000"
                   enableLookups="false"
                   URIEncoding="utf-8"
                    />

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

            <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Context path="/" docBase="ROOT" reloadable="true"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>

Tried multiple options but not working. Please help what else I can do to make it working.
Springboot war is not successfully deployed and it is starting. API's are not accessible
Getting 404 while accessing.
API's endpoints are not accessible.

"Not working" is a very broad category. Be specific about what you are running and what errors you get.

Which tomcat version are you using?

@SimonJacobs It is getting 404 for api endpoints

@M.Deinum 9.0.88

Spring Boot 3 requires Tomcat 10 or higher, it won't work on lower versions. It requires a JakartaEE capable Servlet container.

As far as I read threads, springboot doesn’t support tomcat 10
